# Maximum and minimum distance of two points

Tags: plane-geometry

Consider six distinct points in a plane. Let $m$ and $M$ denote respectively the minimum and the maximum distance between any pair of points.

Show that $M/m \geqslant \sqrt{3}$.

Comment: If we draw a line $y=x$ then max distance between point $0,0 and 6,6$ is $72^{0.5},$ minimum is $6$ thus $M/m=2^{0.5}$ can you make the question clearer

Comment: @ArchisWelankar but there are 6 distinct points

Answer (score 4):

Assume otherwise.
Pick two points $A,B$ at distance $M$ (The small dots in the following image)

[image]

Then all other points are in the closed lens-shaped area bounded by the  circles of radius $M$ around $A$ and $B$ (big circles in above image). In particular, they must be in the ten blue triangles shown. 
As the blue triangles have side length $\frac M{\sqrt 3}$, each of them can contain at most one of the points (including on the boundary).
After taking away those already occupied by $A$ and B$, there are only four blue triangles left. We conclude that each of the top two and each of the bottom two blue triangles contains one of the four remaining points.

Next consider the red lines: The shape bounded from above by the top red line and from below by the two small circles has diameter $<\frac M{\sqrt 3}$, hence can contain at most one point.
We conclude that one of the points must be above the top red line.
By the same argument, one of the points must be below the bottom red line.
But then these two points are more than $M$ apart - contradiction!

Comment: How do you derive the contradiction? It is easy to find two points in one such area which are between $\frac{M}{\sqrt3}$ and $M$ apart.

Comment: A more detailed sketch will make that clearer - coming soon

Comment: Sorry, but this proof CAN'T POSSIBLY be correct. It would work with just five points, and for five points the result is not true. (Consider a regular pentagon). https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diagonal+of+regular+pentagon   Congrats on the upvotes!

Comment: @mathguy OK, a bit more of clarification was needed. But with the right sketch and additional arguments, it should now be clearer

Comment: @Hagen: Don't be dishonest. This is not a "clarification" but replacing your incorrect argument with a correct one. You stated something quite different in your first posting; editing it is fine, being dishonest is not.